# Precisava de ajuda sobre posicionamento com flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class"container">      
<header>
<nav class="menu">
    <h1 class="logo">Commerce</h1>
    <ul class=menuLinks>
        <li><a>Option1</li></a>
        <li><a>Option2</li></a>
        <li><a>Option3</li></a>
        <li><a>Option4</li></a>
        <li><a>Option5</li></a>
    <ul>
<nav>
<header>
```

Eu queria alinhar a parte "logo" na esquerda do menu, e a parte da class "menulinks" ficasse a direita e que ficasse tambem bem separada os "menulinks" com o da logo tipo uma margem, e que tambem ocupasse 90% da class "menu" de uma forma que nao quebrasse o código usando o flexbox, atualmente me encontro com dificuldade para fazer esse tipo de posicionamento!

Answer (score 0):

Olá. sugiro pesquisar um pouco sobre a propriedade `justify-content`.
Pelo que eu entendi você quer algo mais ou menos assim:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class"container">      
<header>
<h1 class="logo">Commerce</h1>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class=menuLinks>
        <li><a>Option1</li></a>
        <li><a>Option2</li></a>
        <li><a>Option3</li></a>
        <li><a>Option4</li></a>
        <li><a>Option5</li></a>
    <ul>
<nav>
<header>
```